# i want to load 10k data in my bootstrap data table in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables

I have **10000** rows on table in my database. When ever I try to load all my data, page stop working error comes. Is there limit of loading data in data table? And if yes, then how can i increase that limit?

```
 <?php 
 foreach($recs as $ans)
 {
?>
<tr>                                            
    <td><center><?php echo $ans['sz_StockID']; ?></center></td>
</tr>
<?php
 }
?>
```

Controller:

```
$this->check_session();
$data['recs']=$this->am->get_diamonds();
```

Model:

```
$q=$this->db->query('select * from `table_name`');
return $q->result_array();
```

Comment: Show us your code and the error

Comment: error number 500 and i use simple for loop for call data.when there is 2000 data its display all things properly but when data goes up to 2000 error comes @TreeNguyen

Comment: Please edit your post to add your code into that.

Comment: please check now @TreeNguyen

Comment: What do you mean by `10 000` data? Do you mean you have `10K` rows?

Comment: yes @SalimIbrogimov

Comment: The code that you provide it's doing nothing, but iterates an array, please add more code, which will help us. Thanks!

Comment: please check now controller and model code @SalimIbrogimov

Comment: see the result of: `echo $this->db->error();`

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: no any error output is: Array ( [code] => 0 [message] => ) @SalimIbrogimov

Comment: Please limit rows, for testing purpose: `$q=$this->db->query('select * from table_name limit 10');`

Comment: when i print $data it will show me all on controller but when i send it to view page in data table it will stop  working. @SalimIbrogimov

Comment: Okay, how do you passing the `$data` onto `view` from `controller`??? add code if it's possible?

Comment: $this->load->view('controller_name/view_page_name',$data);@SalimIbrogimov

Comment: in `$data` do you have `recs` item ???

Comment: guys stop talking about nonsense ... he exceeds the memory limit and this is good so - because you should never ever load 10k rows at once ... @Shah Vairag - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47885399/datatable-with-ajax-is-not-working-well-after-use-serverside-true/47885949#47885949 - study my answer and ops question and you should be able to get a solution

Comment: ^ or pagination or Ignited Datatables. Never load 10k rows at once, are you suicidal? ;)

Comment: @sintakonte he said: `when i print $data it will show me all on controller but when i send it to view page in data table it will stop working`

Comment: @Salim fair enough - but it doesn't change the fact that loading 10k rows at once is total nonsense... and this is what i meant, as this discussion went in a wrong direction

Comment: @sintakonte: yes, I agree, with you! )))

Comment: No user will ever compare 10k rows on one screen. Paginate it per 10 or per 100 rows on output. And never query all rows from database but use limit. @sintakonte gave you an example.