# CodeIgniter - How do I sort table at cllient side?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I build my project using Code Igniter. And i'm using to show tables to users.
I'm trying to allow user to sort the data displayed in table sort with date but I not sure how , and I tried to search and can't find solution.

[image]

For example, when user click the ↑ button , the data display will change to ascending order. Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery Datatable

> for more visit
>
> https://datatables.net/

Comment: Yes Definitely work , i also using it with codeigniter

Comment: just tried, it only sort on the current page, its not suitable for large data

Comment: @hatched - datatables are perfectly suitable for large data - because it also has an option to use it as a serverside implentation (https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side) - maybe the following link helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47885399/datatable-with-ajax-is-not-working-well-after-use-serverside-true/47885949#47885949